# Querying one to many relationship in an XML Column

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, cross-apply

I have an XML column in a table.

The table looks has two columns:

- ID
- DepartmentXML

The DepartmentXML typically looks like this:

```
<Root>
    <Department>
        <dID>100</dID>
        <DName>Engineering</DName>
    </Department>
    <Employee>
        <EmployeeID>999</EmployeeID>
        <EName>AAA BBB</EName>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
        <EmployeeID>888</EmployeeID>
        <EName>XXX YYY</EName>
    </Employee>
</Root>
```

How to query this XML, to get result like this?

```
   +------------------------------------------+
   |dID|DepartmentName|EmployeeID|EmployeeName|
   +------------------------------------------+
   |100|Engineering   |999       |AAA BBB     |
   |100|Engineering   |888       |XXX YYY     |
   +------------------------------------------+
```

I know CROSS APPLY may have to be used, but the syntax for this particular scenario is very difficult for me to understand.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

First a *mockup table* to simulate your issue:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, DepartmentXml XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
(N'<Root>
    <Department>
        <dID>100</dID>
        <DName>Engineering</DName>
    </Department>
    <Employee>
        <EmployeeID>999</EmployeeID>
        <EName>AAA BBB</EName>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
        <EmployeeID>888</EmployeeID>
        <EName>XXX YYY</EName>
    </Employee>
</Root>');
```

--The query

```
SELECT t.ID
      ,t.DepartmentXml.value('(/Root/Department/dID/text())[1]','int') AS DepartmentId
      ,t.DepartmentXml.value('(/Root/Department/DName/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS DepartmentName
      ,A.e.value('(EmployeeID/text())[1]','int') AS EmployeeId
      ,A.e.value('(EName/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS EmployeeName
FROM @tbl t
OUTER APPLY t.DepartmentXml.nodes('/Root/Employee') A(e);
```

The idea in short:

- We can pick the row's ID directly
- We can read the department's information directly from the XML (non-repeating)
- We can retrieve repeating nodes using `APPLY` with `.nodes()`.
- We can use a relative XPath against `A.e` to get the employee's data